# How can I append a value to dynamically generated options with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating dynamic options from Facebook array. I want to append the `access_token` to the selected page option value. After looking around, I don't understand how to modify my code to make it work.

**Markup**

```
   <!-- DISPLAY CONNECT BUTTON -->
<button type="button" id="connect" onclick="login();return false;">

 <!-- DISPLAY SELECT OPTION LIST-->
 <div id="pageContainer" style="display:none;">
<select id="pages" style="display:none;"></select>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//open login dialog onClick
  function login() {  
FB.login(function(){
  FB.api('/me/accounts/',  function(response) {
            var pages = document.getElementById('pages');
            var pageContainer = document.getElementById('pageContainer');
            pages.style.display = 'block';
            pageContainer.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("connect").style.display="none";
            for(var i =0; i < response.data.length; i++)
            {
              pages[i] = new Option(response.data[i].name);
            }
          }
        );

}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the `Option` object looks like this:

```
new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);
```

If you want to set the `value` of the new option you create just use the second parameter to set the value:

```
pages[i] = new Option(response.data[i].name, VALUE);
```

(I'm not sure where you take the value from, just put it there).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the constructor but the example that I get is confusing. So to append the access_token should I do something like `pages[i] = new Option(response.data[i].name, response.data[i].access_token);` ?

Comment: I'm not where where you get the `access_token` from. If you have `val` inside `response.data[i]` and it's an object that has `access_token` property - then you can take it from there...